# How to sort a list of an array depending by an object value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

we need to list an array sorting by an object value.

We have a list of films, sorted by alphabetical order, but we want to sort by genres.

here is the code listing in alphabetical order.

```
<?php
    foreach ($films as $film_id => $film) {

    echo "<ul>";
    echo '<li id="film_thumb">';
    echo '<a href="watch.php?id=' . $film_id . '" alt="ID">';
    echo '<img class="thumb_res" src=" ' . $film["thumb"] . '" alt="' . $film["name"] . '">' ;
    echo '</a>';
    echo '</li>';
    echo "</ul>";
} ?>
```

the function listing in alphabetical order is in the array file

```
sort($films, SORT_FLAG_CASE);
```

Here is the array

```
$films = array ();
    $films[1] = array(
        "name" => "21 Jump Street",
        "year" => "2012",
        "genre" => "Commedia",
        "path" => "media/01.mp4",
        "thumb"=> "media/thumb/01.png",
        );
```

now, we need to create a page that list these items ( film thumb ) in categories, so if i click on genre "Action", the page must to show only selected film genre, and not the others.

Many thanks, Andrea

Comment: Use `array_filter()` to filter array by some value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort your array by genre with `usort()` :

```
usort($films, function($a, $b){
    return strcasecmp($a['genre'], $b['genre']);
});
```

If you want to get films from the selected genre, you can use `array_filter()` :

```
$films = array_filter($films, function($film){
    return $film['genre'] == 'Commedia';
});
```